# Trying to use custom hook gives error "Block-scoped variable 'X' used before its declaration."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to write my first custom hook.

I don't understand why the error is showing, as the function is declared a few lines above where it is called.

Relevant code:

```
function getNextAnswerState(answer: string) {
  switch (answer) {
    case "blank":
      return ("correct");
    case "correct":
      return ("wrong");
    case "wrong":
      return ("forgotten");
    case "forgotten":
      return ("blank");
  }
  return "blank";
}

function useAnswerState() {
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("blank");

  const handleGetNextCellStatus = () => {
    let nextCellStatus = getNextAnswerState(answer)
    setAnswer(nextCellStatus);
  }

  return {answer, handleGetNextCellStatus};
}

interface letterProps {
  cellIndex: number,
  layerSize: number,
  letter: string
}

function LetterCell({cellIndex, layerSize, letter}: letterProps) {
  const {answerStatus, setAnswerToNext} = useAnswerState();
  ...
```

The errors:

[tsserver 2448] [E] Block-scoped variable 'useAnswerState' used before its declaration.

[tsserver 2454] [E] Variable 'useAnswerState' is used before being assigned.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was a small syntax error somewhere.

Comment: where is this syntax error?